# Cannot Create Post

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am unable to create a post, I am a beginner so apology in advance if my question sounds stupid

**Heres The Picture Of My Form Before Hitting Submit:-**
[image]

**Heres The Picture After Hitting Submit:-**
[image]

**I cant seem to find any error**

**Here's My Controller:-**

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $data = request()->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
      ]);

       auth()->user()->profile()->post()->create($data
       );
       return redirect('/h');
```

**And I do need to pass in "user_id" in it**

Please **Help** and **Thanks** in advance

Comment: Are you filling out the form? This is validation; there's no errors logged per-se, but the code after `->validate()` will not run if validation fails... In shorter words, your code is working exactly as expected.

Comment: I assume you checked the names of the form elements to make sure they match? Also use the auth object to get the user id on the back end

Comment: $post = new Post($data);
 auth()->user()->profile()->post()->create($post); will create post, i will suggest your create relation between user table and post table don't go through profile table.

Comment: @umefarooq I have already created a relation between user and post and profile, and i did use ur **"$post = new Post($data); auth()->user()->profile()->post()->create($post); will create post"** now the error i am having is **Call to undefined method App\User::post()**

Comment: @CodeJunkie The reason it was not showing any error was that the names were not correct and can u please show me how u want me to use the auth function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller validation seems correct.

You are redirected back to your form since the request doesn't contain the 'title' and 'body' values. These values are 'required' according to your validation array.

Add this line to your controller to debug and see what the request actually contains:

`dd(request()->all());`

In your view, make sure your html form inputs have their respective name attributes set correctly:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/your-route">
  @csrf
  <input name="title" ...>
  <input name="body" ...>
</form>
```

---

And to answer your last question: No, you do not need to add the `user_id` to your $data array; Laravel will do it for you since you are chaining the create() method from the authenticated user instance with this line: `auth()->user()->profile()->post()->create($data);`

You could also call the create() method directly from the Post class, in which case the user_id should be specified:

```php
Post::create([
    'user_id' => 1,
    'title' => 'My title',
    'body' => 'My body',
]);
```

Comment: u were right the problem was in the input names but now i have changed my codes to ```$post = new Post($data);
       auth()->user()->post()->create($post);
      ```     and  added ```protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];``` to my **Post** model and the error that i'm getting now is **Call to undefined method App\User::post()**

Comment: Use either `$post = new Post($data); $post->save() `, or `auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);` but not both. It's the same, just different syntax. Your error is saying the User model doesn't have a method called post(). Since I imagine a user has many post**s**, your relationship method on the user model must be called `posts()` plural with an 's'.